# Prolog efficiency: facts unification or list membership?

Tags: prolog

Given these facts:

```
pos(a,1).
pos(b,2).
pos(c,3).
```

I want to find the position of a character. For example, `pos(b,P)` P=2.

Is it better to convert these facts to a list and do a membership check, like so:

```
member(X/P,[a/1,b/2,c/3])
```

I assume that the first option is better, but can anyone explain the pros and cons of each approach?

Note, this is just a simple example. I will have many facts, e.g 100-1000 and will have to do this check many more times, e.g. 100k+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A list implies a linear scan. I.e. the time to locate a element is proportional, in the worst case, to the number of elements in the list. But for facts for a static predicate, most Prolog implementations apply when possible what's called *first argument indexing*, which in this case would allow Prolog to call the correct clause for your `pos/2` predicate when the first argument is instantiated without first trying (and failing) all the clauses that precede the correct one. Thus, you're comparing linear time, O(N), access to constant time access, O(1).

Comment: Does first argument indexing apply if the first argument is a list? e.g. pos([a,1]).

Comment: That's sometimes named "deep indexing" but I'm not aware of any compiler doing it, although it have been discussed in some mailing lists. Note, however, that first-argument indexing can usually distinguish between an empty list (which, in reality, is not a list) and a non-empty list. Also note that some Prolog compilers provide nowadays multi-argument indexing (with or without some predicate declaration) but first-argument indexing is the only thing you can expect to be there when writing portable code.

Answer (score 1):

Using facts should be more efficient (although, at only 3 items, the difference is probably negligible).  All of prolog is built on looking up facts/rules, so it needs to be pretty efficient.  Using a list is more flexible; it will be much easier to switch between sets of facts this way, for example.